# Can't test a controller when passing a hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have two objects, Course and TeacherRight. I create TeacherRight with a from placed on the Course 'show' view. I pass course_id to the TeacherRight controller as a hidden field:

```
=form_for(@right) do |f|
  =hidden_field_tag :course_id, @course.id
  %ul
    %li=f.collection_select :user_id, User.order(:name)-@course.teachers, :id, :name, include_blank: false
    %li=f.submit
```

The controller:

```
class TeacherRightsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @teacher_right = course.teacher_rights.build(teacher_right_params)
    @teacher_right.save
    redirect_to course
  end

  private
    def teacher_right_params
      params.require(:teacher_right).permit(:user_id)
    end
  #only owner can add teachers to course
  def can_edit(course)
    redirect_to root_url unless current_user == course.owner
  end
```

It works fine, but I can't write a test for it! I wrote

```
class TeacherRightsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @owner_1 = users(:owner_1)
    @course = courses(:course)
    @teacher_1 = users(:teacher_1)
  end

  test "teacher can't add teachers" do
    log_in_as(@teacher_1)
    assert_no_difference('TeacherRight.count') do
      post :create, {teacher_right: {course_id:@course.id, user_id: @teacher_1.id }}
    end
  end
```

But it gives an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Course with 'id'=
            app/controllers/teacher_rights_controller.rb:4:in `create'
```

As I can see,

```
post :create, {teacher_right: {course_id:@course.id, user_id: @teacher_2.id, }}
```

doesn't pass course_id in a way the controller can consume. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidentally are posting the `:course_id` inside the `:teacher_right` hash, so it will show up as `params[:teacher_right][:course_id]` instead of the desired `params[:course_id]`.

Your POST request should look like this:

```
post :create, {
  course_id: @course.id,
  teacher_right: { user_id: @teacher_1.id }
}
```